# Add commands to the instance manager with association to public method of two clases

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

I want to be able to add commands to the manager instance and associate those commands with invoking public methods from both class A and class B when they're executed. I know that in order to achieve this the class Command should have a pointer to a class member function instead of a regular `function (void (T::*Handler)()` instead of `void(*Handler)() )`, but I found myself lost in how exactly I can achieve this. I have the following code:

```
typedef void (*Handler)();

class Command {
    public:
        Command(char*, Handler);
    private:
        char* name;
        Handler handler;
};

class CommandManager {
    public:
        CommandManager();
        void addCommand(Command*);
        void execute(char* commandName);
    private:
        Command** commands;
}



// implementation, copy constructor and destructor should be ignored at this point since        they do
// not affect directly the question I'm trying to find an answer for.
```

I have another two classes. Let's say they're class A and class B, both having methods with return type void
and with no params. I also have class C which contains member variables of type pointers to A and B:

```
class C {
    public:
     // some public stuff here
    private:
     A* a;
     B* b;  
     CommandManager* manager;
}
```

Note: It might be easier to introduce inheritance and abstract class but this is something I am limitted not to use(do not ask why :) ), so is there any way to do what I want?

Comment: sure, my mistake. post eddited. however, question still valid.

Comment: Unrelated, I have no idea what the `command` class is for.  It seems like `CommandManager` should be a mapping of names to handlers: `std::multimap<std::string, std::function<void()>>`

Comment: it does exactly that. mapping between string and procedures to be executed. however, trying to avoid abstract data structures and inheritance as well.

Comment: I see the following problem: all of you guys lack the context where all these things happen. The purpose of the Command and the class C is to read user input from the console and to be something like a facade to a much more complex system. So I want to be able to invoke different class methods depending on what the user has typed in the standard input.

Comment: If `CommandManager` was a `map` like I wrote above, it could do exactly that.  What I don't understand is what the `command` class's responsability is.

Comment: nothing more than a pair of string and a function

Comment: I _see_ that it's nothing more than a pair of a string and a function.  What I'm saying is that I don't see that you _need_ a pair of a string and a function.  You need handlers, and a thing that maps strings to handlers.  You have both of those already.

Answer (score 0):

The "best" solution:

```
typedef std::function<void()> Handler;
//std::function<void()> is the magic bit you were asking about

class Command {
    public:
        Command(const std::string& name, Handler) {}
    private:
        std::string name;
        Handler handler;
};

class CommandManager {
    public:
        CommandManager();
        void addCommand(std::unique_ptr<Command>);
        void execute(const std::string& commandName);
    private:
        std::vector<Command> commands;
};
```

and then functionoids go like this

```
struct A { 
    void operator()() {std::cout << "A";}
};
Command  ACommand = {"A", A()}; 
//constructs a temporary A, 
//then a temporary std::function<void()> is constructed which stores the A
//then the Command stores this function.

struct B {
    void named_function() {std::cout << "B";}
};
B bobj;
Command  BCommand = {"B", std::bind(&B::named_function, &bobj)}; 
//bind constructs a functionoid binding the bobj as the "this" of the member function
//then a temporary std::function<void()> is constructed which stores the functionoid
//then the Command stores this function.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `this` pointer passed implicitly to every member function. This makes the signature of the functions of `A` different from those of `B`.

Without using templates and inheritance, the easiest way would be to declare the functions of `A` and `B` as `static`. Then, there is no `this` pointer, and the functions can be assigned to the function pointer `handler`.

Because it's not likely to be powerful enough, here another way, but I must say it's a kludge, it would really be better to use inheritance.

Define

```
typedef Handler void (*Handler)(void *);
```

and implement the static command handlers as follows

```
void A::doit(void *arg)
{
  A *newthis = (A*)arg;
  newthis->UseMembersOfA();
}
```

Comment: The easiest way should be to define a global A and B pointers and then   global wrapper functions that invoke the A and B methods, but this is  quite radical workaround. However, templates are valid solution, so if  there's any it would be nice.

Comment: Then Mooing Duck's solution seems the way to go, but I'm still trying to assimilate, too ;-)